# What is 100Mbps in ethernet, is that including both transmit and receiving bps?

Tags: ethernet, half-duplex

I have one doubt, my LAN card is 100Mbps is that including both transmit and receiving bps? OR  100 Mbps of transmitting + 100 Mbps of receiving

Kindly someone clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100BASE-T (fast ethernet over 2 wire pairs) is full duplex, meaning 100Mbit per direction, simultaneously.

It is possible to configure a 100Mbit network interface in half duplex, meaning that the total bandwidth available for send+receive is 100Mbit (as opposed to 200Mbit for full duplex)